# How to make a Button()s state continuous?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I have a for loop initiating buttons in a grid, and I want the buttons state to togglable, instead of turning off once the mouse button is no longer held. I also need that to know which button called the buttons' function, because I'm initializing a number of them in the same for loop, meaning they all call the same function once activated, anyone know how to help me?

EDIT:

minimal working example:

```py
import tkinter as gui

def createWindow():
    window = gui.Tk()
    window.title("GoL")
    icon = gui.PhotoImage(file='Not showing ya\'ll my files.png')
    window.iconphoto(True, icon)
    window.config(background="black")
    label = gui.Label(window,\
        text="Generation:",\
        bg="black",\
        fg="white",\
        font=("Consolas",20))
    label.pack()
    return window

def newBoard(x = 10,y = 10):
    window = createWindow()
    for i in range(0, y):
            for j in range(1, x+1):
                button = gui.Button(window,bg="black",height=1,width=2,command=changeState)
            button.place(x=23*(j-1),y=23*(i+2))
    window.mainloop()
```

what I want is the function `changeState` to change the

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example of what you tried and what you need? Also use a `lambda` to pass in an identifier for the button. Are you putting the buttons in a list?

Comment: You might want to research Radiobuttons and the `indicatoron` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by keeping a list of buttons (`buttons`), then using a lambda function to pass the row/column number to the button command function, which then allows you to change the properties of the selected button. In this case it toggles between black and white background colours.

```
def changeState(i, j):
    global buttons
    b = buttons[i][j]
    b.config(bg = "white") if b.cget("bg") != "white" else b.config(bg = "black")

def newBoard(x = 10,y = 10):
    global buttons
    window = createWindow()
    buttons = []
    for i in range(0, y):
        row = []
        for j in range(1, x+1):
            button = gui.Button(window,bg="black",height=1,width=2,command=lambda i=i, j=j-1: changeState(i,j))
            row.append(button)
            button.place(x=23*(j-1),y=23*(i+2))
        buttons.append(row)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I already solved this problem, but as I reached the exact same solution you proposed here, I'm still gonna accept it